# Why did Nginx start proxying all ports to port 80 out of nowhere?

Tags: nginx

This is my configuration file:

```
server {
    server_name domain1.com www.domain1.com;

    location / {
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_pass http://localhost:3000;
    }

    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/domain1.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/domain1.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot
}

server {
    if ($host = www.domain1.com) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot

    if ($host = domain1.com) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot

    listen 80;
    server_name domain1.com www.domain1.com;
    return 404; # managed by Certbot
}


server {
    server_name domain2.com www.domain2.com;

    location / {
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_pass http://localhost:4000;
    }

    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/domain2.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/domain2.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot
}

server {
    if ($host = www.domain2.com) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


    if ($host = domain2.com) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


    server_name domain2.com www.domain2.com;
    listen 80;
    return 404; # managed by Certbot
}

server {
   listen <server-ip>:80;

   location / {
      proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
      proxy_pass http://localhost:4000;
   }
}
```

I'm running 3 websites on the same server using this config file:

- domain1.com which points to port 3000
- domain2.com which points to port 3001
- main server IP which points to port 4000

All domains are automatically configured to use SSL, which is done by Certbot.

This morning, the agency that I work with called me and told me that domain1.com and domain2.com are both showing the server on port 80. Out of nowhere! I tested this once and it was working fine. Overnight, it changed to that port. Why would this happen and how can I avoid it or make my config better?

Comment: your configuration looks like a "normal" certbot modified configuration file. The config woud redirect all traffic from port 80 to 443. Is the redirect to 80 still happens? How is initiating the redirect? NGINX or the Application itself? Are there anything printed to the access or error log? You can improve the proxy settings. https://www.nginx.com/blog/5-performance-tips-for-node-js-applications/ check out the proxy settings from this blog post.

Comment: @TimoStark No no, you got me wrong. It is redirecting from 80 to 443. Nothing wrong with the SSL. My problem is domain1.com and domain2.com being redirected to port 80 and not 3000 and 3001, respectively.

Comment: Ahh got it. Just to be clear. You are saying the NGINX is not proxying traffic to you backend services to the right port? 80 instead of 3000 and 3001? It is not a redirect at all. This is a important difference here.

Comment: @TimoStark Yes, correct. I'll edit the post now.

Comment: Thanks. Back to your problem. Are there anything written in the error.log? Are you able to turn on the debug mode and check the error.log again? This should tell you the proxy_pass NGINX is sending the traffic to.Alternatively you can add `$upstream_addr` to you access log format defined in nginx.conf.

Comment: @TimoStark Nope, nothing in error.log, just 4 rows of `signal process started`